# Checking trade in value for video games

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I'm trying to get the trade in value on a video game using the python amazon api. http://python-amazon-product-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

I have tried running this code:

```
from amazonproduct import API
api = API(locale='us')
items = api.item_search('VideoGames', Keywords='Metal Gear Solid',IsEligibleForTradeIn ='1')
for item in items:
    if item.ItemAttributes.TradeInValue.Amount:
            print '%s: %d' % (item.ItemAttributes.Title, item.ItemAttributes.TradeInValue.Amount)
```

But I get an AttributeError claiming there is no such child "TradeInValue"

This code works until I ask for trade in value, is tradeInValue a valid attribute for video games?

**EDIT**: Print out for `print item.__dict__`

```
{'ItemAttributes': <Element {http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}ItemAttributes at 0x7f7a1b117128>, 'ASIN': 'B00JKM06HG', 'ItemLinks': <Element {http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}ItemLinks at 0x7f7a1b1177e8>, 'DetailPageURL': 'http://www.amazon.com/Metal-Gear-Solid-Phantom-Pain-PlayStation/dp/', 'ParentASIN': 'B00KVVSONI'}
```

Comment: can you `print item.__dict__` and see what attrs are available?

Comment: @BAH it seemed to not have tradeinvalue attribute when I print that but there also seems to be a lot of attributes I know are there that don't show up as well

Comment: what about `print item.ItemAttributes.__dict__`?

Comment: @BAH oh bummer `{'Title': 'Metal Gear Solid V: Ground Zeroes - PlayStation 4 Standard Edition', 'ProductGroup': 'Video Games', 'Manufacturer': 'Konami'}` looks like it doesn't have the trade in value. do you know of another way?

Comment: @Bah it does the same attributes with books though? which I thought for sure has a trade in value based off other questions

Comment: Looking at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054215/fetching-amazon-buyback-trade-in-price is there an `item_lookup` function? And sorry, I'm not sure - never used the amazon api. Just going based off what you're providing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107444/discussion-between-bah-and-user3470987).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching some of the info provided by you and the docs for [item_search](http://python-amazon-product-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/operations.html?highlight=response%20group#amazonproduct.api.API.item_search) and [item_lookup](http://python-amazon-product-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/operations.html?highlight=response%20group#amazonproduct.api.API.item_lookup)

It looks like `item_lookup` (and I presume `item_search`) can return ***some*** or ***all*** of the attributes, depending on the response group specified in the request. By default, `item_lookup`, returns an item’s ASIN, Manufacturer, ProductGroup, and Title of the item.

While going through the available [ResponseGroups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CHAP_ResponseGroupsList.html) on AWS, I discovered `ItemAttributes`, which also returns `TradeInValue` as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_ItemAttributes.html). I don't have an Amazon Developer account set up, however, you could try changing your search parameters to the below (and see if the additional attributes show up)

```
items = api.item_search(
    'VideoGames',
    Keywords='Metal Gear Solid',
    IsEligibleForTradeIn='1',
    ResponseGroup='ItemAttributes'
)
```